# Xbee and Arduino acting strangely regardless of code

Tags: arduino, xbee

I'm trying to write a simple code that sends a string to an xbee and one that sends the string back, I was able to do this with XCTU via console, but I want my arduino to send the string.

I was able to use a simple code that read my output from the serial monitor and sends it to an xbee connected via usb adapter, the problem is that I now wrote the code so it sends a predefined string like in the screenshot, but when I write into the monitor it still sends whatever I wrote instead of the static string. I'm also unable to read what I type into the xbee console from XCTU.

I'd love any assistance in this, I've tried uploading and resetting everything to no avail.

[Screenshot of problem with the current code of the arduino on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvlhw.png)

Comment: UPDATE: I've managed to send from the XCTU console into the arduino monitos and from the monitor to the console by uploading the following code:
void setup(){}
void loop(){}
which makes even less sense to me, unless reading from and to the console is the default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you were using an Arduino to try to communicate with your XBee Zigbee module.

One thing you have to check is the connection between the TX and RX signals on the Arduino side and on the XBee Zigbee side.

I've helped someone on another forum who used this Seed Studio XBee shield :
[image: Seed Studio Arduino XBee Shield]
If you look at the schematics of this shield, the XBee 'DOut' signal (Tx) is wired to the XB_TX line which can be connected to any of the AJ2 pin with a jumper.

Now on the Arduino side :

[image: Arduino UART]

On this extract of the Arduino schematics, we can see that the ATMEGA UART has it's RX signal connected to pin 2 of the CPU which is wired to the IOL (AJ2) pin 0.

So, that means that on this shield, the jumper have to be placed between XB_TX and pin 0 of AJ2 to connect the XBee transmission signal (output) to the ATMEGA reception signal (input) [and also XB_RX have to be connected pin 1 of AJ2].

As you didn't mention what kind of shield you were using, you have to double check this point which is a common issue when using serial communication.

In a general way, ALWAYS connect 1 output to N input (except open-drain or open-collector outputs which can be connected together to make a wired OR but which finally have to be connected to N inputs)

Hope this helps

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell on the documentation Xbee "hijacks" the serial system. Instead try blinking an LED to confirm data is being received and sent.
[documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoXbeeShield)

Comment: Thank you, I've managed to set them both on API mode which lets me send and receive hexadecimal data from XCTU, but so far I can't read or send the data back, so far I can get the data I sent within the receiver's console, but not from the arduino terminal, how would I go around to setting a LED to light up if Serial.available() always reports a 0?